# Python pandas create a new row within dataframe based on a conditions on certain rows above

Tags: python, pandas, conditional-statements

I have the following dataframe,

[image: dataframe]

I want to create a new row called test within the index column, which checks if the `pd` row is the same sign (negative is FALSE and positive is TRUE) as the `cn` row. The new row would say TRUE if and only if both `pd` and `cn` are the same sign (TRUE and positive or FALSE and negative). NaN is considered 0 and I want it to count as a different sign.

So I want the final result to look like this,

[image]

I know how to add new columns based on conditions and `np.where`, but I don't know how to add things row-wise.

I have no idea where to start. Any help with like examples or advice on where to start would be great.

Update:

I have added the code for creating the dataframe,

```
data = {'x1':[-0.00137,True,0.7],'x2':[0.00658,False,0.7], 'x3':[0.004332,np.nan,np.nan], 'x4':[-0.005762,np.nan,np.nan],
        'x5':[0.005905,np.nan,np.nan],'x6':[0.001333,False,0.7],'x7':[0.001611,False,0.7],'x8':[-0.00089,False,1],'x9':[0.000042,np.nan,np.nan],'x10':[0.004027,np.nan,np.nan],} 
  
df = pd.DataFrame(data, index =['pd', 
                                'cn', 
                                'td2',])
```

here are the test results i wish to reproduce,

```
data2 = {'x1':[False],'x2':[False], 'x3':[False], 'x4':[False],
        'x5':[False],'x6':[False],'x7':[False],'x8':[True],'x9':[False],'x10':[False],} 

df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2, index =['test'])
```

Comment: i added the code to create the frame in the post, sorry about that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a simple comparison:

```
df.loc['test', :] = df.loc['pd'].ge(0).eq(df.loc['cn'])
```

Output:

```
           x1       x2        x3        x4        x5        x6        x7       x8       x9       x10
pd   -0.00137  0.00658  0.004332 -0.005762  0.005905  0.001333  0.001611 -0.00089  4.2e-05  0.004027
cn       True    False       NaN       NaN       NaN     False     False    False      NaN       NaN
td2       0.7      0.7       NaN       NaN       NaN       0.7       0.7        1      NaN       NaN
test    False    False     False     False     False     False     False     True    False     False
```

---

**Explanation:**

In pandas, `ge` means "greater or equal" just like `>=`. Therefore, positive values will return `True` (and False for negative values) so that we can compare them element-wise with `cn` index (it's `numpy` under the hood).

Note that `NaN` values will always return `False` (I think it's what you want). If you want to add a meaning to `NaN` values, you can replace `df.loc['cn']` by `df.loc['cn'].fillna(False)`, where you can choose to replace `NaN` with `True` or `False` values.

Comment: How does this work? Check if the pd row is greater than or equal to cn?

Comment: Exactly, @anarchy. You can replace it with `gt` to only consider greater values, but this would return `False` to zeros. I've updated the answer with an explanation.

Comment: Hey if you use greater or equal already why do you use .eq() after?

Comment: Because `.gt` just returns a bool array telling us if the `pd` values are positive or not, and you want to compare it with another bool array (`cn`).

Answer (score 1):

You should definetely consider sharing your data as text next time, so that we can reproduce your case with the original data.

Anyway, you can do operations row-wise by accessing them individually using `.loc`, like

```
import numpy as np

cn_row = [0 if np.isnan(i) else 1 if i else -1 for i in df.loc['cn']]

df.loc['test'] = (df.loc['pd'] * cn_row) > 0
df.loc['test'] = df.loc['test'].astype(bool)
```

Edit: Now with your code it is easy to test. We have the following output:

```
           x1       x2        x3        x4        x5        x6        x7       x8       x9       x10
pd   -0.00137  0.00658  0.004332 -0.005762  0.005905  0.001333  0.001611 -0.00089  4.2e-05  0.004027
cn       True    False       NaN       NaN       NaN     False     False    False      NaN       NaN
td2       0.7      0.7       NaN       NaN       NaN       0.7       0.7        1      NaN       NaN
test    False    False     False     False     False     False     False     True    False     False
```

Comment: i added a code to create the dataframe in my post, sorry about that

Comment: x4 is supposed to be False as well because its NaN, I consider it a third sign if that makes sense?

Comment: Oh, you're right.. didin't notice that, sorry. I'm gonna correct it

Comment: Hey thanks for this! I have another question if you could entertain me, what if i had a third condition, if I saw 0 in pd and NaN in cn and I want it to appear as True as well?

Comment: In this case you coul use another list comprehension like

`pd_row = [1 if i > 0 else -1 if i < 0 else 0]`

And then you can create the `test` row by directly comparing both rows, such as

`df.loc['test'] = np.array(cn_row) == np.array(pd_row)`

Answer (score 0):

As your data is, it would be better to work with transposed DataFrame.
In this case, you could just add the column 'test' as follows

```
new = data.T
new['test'] = [True if new.iloc[row[pd]>0 and new.iloc[row]['cn']==True else False for row in range(new.shape[0])]
```